# The probability of a die rolling a given number at least $x$ times over the course of $n$ rolls

Tags: probability

Say you have a $2000$-sided die, which you roll $2000$ times. I know the probability that you will get any given number (let's just say $1$) at least once in those $2000$ rolls is $1-.9995^{2000}$, i.e., $63.22\text{%}$. But how do you find the probability that you will roll a $1$ at least **twice** during a series of $2000$ rolls?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the exact answer instead of an approximation, note first that the statement *roll a one at least twice* is the opposite of *roll a one at most once*.

It is much easier to calculate the latter probability than the former.

$P(\text{at least twice}) = 1 - P(\text{at most once}) = 1 - (P(\text{exactly once}) + P(\text{exactly zero times}))$

$P(\text{exactly once}) = 2000\cdot \frac{1}{2000}\cdot (\frac{1999}{2000})^{1999}$

$P(\text{exactly zero times}) = (\frac{1999}{2000})^{2000}$

So, $P(\text{at least twice}) = 1 - 2000\cdot \frac{1}{2000}\cdot (\frac{1999}{2000})^{1999} - (\frac{1999}{2000})^{2000}\approx0.2642$

---

This used the **Binomial Theorem**

> For $n$ independent trials each with probability of success $p$, the probability of getting exactly $r$ successes is $\binom{n}{r} p^r (1-p)^{n-r}$

Comment: Can you explain in more depth about how you find P(exactly once)? I guess what I really want to understand is the general method for finding P(exactly x times).

Comment: @Ishouldknowthis By the binomial theorem, $P(\text{exactly r times}) = \binom{2000}{r}\cdot(\frac{1}{2000})^r\cdot(\frac{1999}{2000})^{2000-r}$.  To generalize further to additional examples, replace the $2000$ in the exponent and in the combination with the number of trials, and replace $\frac{1}{2000}$ with probability of success and $\frac{1999}{2000}$ with probability of failure.

Comment: Thank you! The binomial theorem is exactly what I was looking for but I didn't know it by name.

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest to find first the probability $p$ of getting one or fewer $1$'s. Then the probability of getting a $1$ at least twice is $1-p$.

The probability we have zero $1$'s is 
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2000}\right)^{2000}.\tag{1}$$

Now we find the probability of exactly one $1$. That $1$ can occur in any one of $2000$ places. The probability it occurs in a particular place is $\frac{1}{2000}$, and the probability it does not occur in the remaining $1999$ places is $\left(1-\frac{1}{2000}\right)^{1999}$, for a total of 
$$2000\cdot\frac{1}{2000}\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{2000}\right)^{1999},\tag{2}$$
Add (1) and (2) to find $p$, and finally calculate $1-p$.

**Another way:** We use the **Poisson approximation**. The mean number of $1$'s is $\lambda=2000\cdot \frac{1}{2000}$. The number $X$ of $1$'s has approximately Poisson distribution parameter $\lambda=1$. So the probability that $X=0$ is approximately $e^{-1}\frac{1^0}{0!}$, and the probability that $X=1$ is approximately $e^{-1}\frac{1^1}{1!}$. So the probability that $X\ge 2$ is approximately $1-2e^{-1}$.

If you do both calculations, you will find that here the Poisson approximation gives an answer very close to the truth.

Answer (score 0):

$p = \dfrac{1}{2,000} = 0.0005, q = 1 - p = 1- 0.0005 = 0.9995, n = 2,000, k = 2, \mu = np = 2,000\cdot 0.0005 = 1, \sigma = \sqrt{npq} = \sqrt{0.9995} =0.9997$, We want to find: $P(x\geq 2)$. We can use normal approximation to the binomial distribution. Thus:
$P(x\geq 2) \approx P(x \geq 1.5) = P\left(z \geq \dfrac{1.5-1}{0.9997}\right) = P(z \geq 0.5) = 1- P(z < 0.5)=1-0.6915 = 0.3085$

Comment: "As a general rule this normal approximation can be used whenever $np$ and $np(1-p)$ are at least $5$" http://courses.wcupa.edu/rbove/Berenson/10th%20ed%20CD-ROM%20topics/section6_5.pdf Due to the small values of $np$ and $npq$ in this case, it is not recommended to use a normal approximation as it was not very accurate.  When $np$ and $npq$ are both greater than $5$ it should vary by only fractions of a percent, but this wound up off by over $4\%$.